# Assign '\0' value to unicode equivalence

Tags: python, c++

I have a downloaded C++ script that at some point does this

```
junk.SetAt(Length, L'\0');
```

I need to write this into a python script and I'm having some troubles. As far as I know ( I'm a C++ beginner ) this will put the unicode decimal value of `\0` at the end of the `junk` string.

So If im right the `ord()` function  does something similar but in python so I have something like this:

```
junk[Length] = ord('\0')
```

This is throwing an error like this one:

```
TypeError: 'unicode' object does not support item assignment
```

This is probably something stupid that I'm missing and I don't see right now, if someone could put me in the right direction I would be so glad.

**Edit** I'm using Python 2.7

**Edit2**
Right now I changed my code to this:

```
junk = junk + ord('\0')
```

The TypeError seems to be solved

Comment: In Python strings (including unicode strings) are not mutable. You can not assign a single character.

Comment: So I have to put it in a new variable?

Comment: That's probably simplest, especially since you can then copy just the length you need.

Comment: Okay, I see now. I was treating it like an array, I've changed to this: `junk = junk + ord('\0')` and now seems to work well. Thank you so much, I feel a bit dumb right now :D

Comment: If `junk` is a string and not a binary object, this would be used to truncate a line. In that case you'd need something else in Python.

Comment: Yeah, it is a string and I use this to delimit the 'usable' content of the string and the junk ( random characters are added to the string after the \0 ). I guess it's working know but I still cannot be sure. I'll tell you guys If something unexpected happens. Thanks all of you for taking the time to read my question and helping me :)

Comment: Can you convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: I'll do when I verify that is working as expected, I couldn't try yet ( the whole script I mean )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It C strings don't have a length, instead the end is marked with a `\0`. In python they have a length. Therefore you **probably** don't need the `\0`.

Unless it inserts the `\0` part way through the string. In this case it is creating a head slice of the string.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help but I don't know if this corresponds to my question. I don't really know if C is so different from C++ but I guess in C++ you're able to get the length of string since I saw something like this in the code: `int Length = text.GetLength();`. Anyways I have to produce an output in python that can be interpreted in C

Comment: Yes C++ is partly C. As in C there are higher order strings, that have length, but also C strings that don't. If you need to inter operate with C, then yes, you will need to do the same trick.